# Django UnknownTimeZoneError

Tags: django, pytz, traceback

Recently I was playing around with google app engine and installed the pytz version for GAE (gaepytz-2011h-py2.7 to be more exact). When I'm trying to open my admin for a Django project now I'm getting I'm getting the above mentioned error with this traceback:

```
gaepytz-2011h-py2.7.egg/pytz/__init__.py in timezone
        raise UnknownTimeZoneError(zone)
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You timezone is probably incorrectly defined. What the exact problem is is impossible to know since you don't state what the zone is.